# Is there a way to determine the coverage of a .PO file?

Tags: localization, gettext

I've got a python program under active development, which uses gettext for translation.

I've got a .POT file with translations, but it is slightly out of date. I've got a script to generate an up-to-date .PO file. Is there a way to check how much of the new .PO file is covered by the .POT file?

Answer (score 5):

> I've got a .POT file with translations, but it is slightly out of date. I've got a script to generate an up-to-date .PO file

I think you mean the other way around. POT files are generated from your source code with PO files containing the translations.

> Is there a way to check how much of the new .PO file is covered by the .POT file?

The Gettext command line [msgmerge](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgmerge-Invocation.html#msgmerge-Invocation) program can be used for syncing your out-of-date PO files with your latest source strings. To create a new PO file from an updated POT you would issue this command:

```
msgmerge old.po new.pot > updated.po
```

The new file will contain all the existing translations that are still valid and add any new source strings. Open it in your favourite PO editor and you should see how many strings now remain untranslated.

---

Update

As pointed out in the comments, you can see how many strings remain untranslated with the "statistics" option of the [msgfmt](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgfmt-Invocation.html) program (normally used for compiling to .mo) e.g.

```
msgfmt --statistics updated.po
```

Or without bothering with the interim file:

```
msgmerge old.po new.pot | msgfmt --statistics -
```

This would produce a synopsis like:

```
 123 translated messages, 77 untranslated messages.
```

Comment: And `msgfmt --statistics --output=/dev/null` shows that information without opening a PO editor.  Can you update your answer?